# MongoAtlas Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to MongoAtlas, however I keep getting
`Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb`

It seems to be that I can connect, but it cannot get my db from MongoAtlas. My try catch error returns me `(node:5964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`

.env

```
PORT = 9055
MONGO_URI =mongodb+srv://<my-db-username>:<my-password>@cluster0.vossd.mongodb.net/<db-name>?
retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const port = Number.parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10);
const mongoUri = process.env.MONGO_URI;

const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const express = require('express');

const Application = require('./application');

const application = Application();

const Health = require('./health');
const Product = require('./product');
const Cart = require('./cart');
const Order = require('./order');

async function main() {
  let db;
  try {
    db = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUri); 
    console.log(db)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

    application.use('/health', Health());
    application.use('/product', Product(db));
    application.use('/cart', Cart(db));
    application.use('/order', Order(db));
    

    const server = application.listen(port, () => {
        const host = server.address().address;
        const port = server.address().port;
        console.log(`Shopping website server up and running, listening at http://${host}:${port}`); 
      });
 }

 main();
```

Everything works fine when I'm connected to my local db, so I'm unsure as to what I'm doing incorrectly. Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Upgrade the driver.

Comment: This `cannot read property 'collection' of undefined` might be misleading as you have caught the error happening on connection. Hence `db` is null so if you access collection it will give this error.

Answer (score 0):

This `cannot read property 'collection' of undefined` might be misleading as you have caught the error happening on connection. Hence `db` is null so if you access collection it will give this error. Below is the sample code from Mongo Atlas.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@test.w7hgn.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }); // <-- note the option
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```